# Why "syntax error near unexpected token"?

Tags: bash, for, error-handling

I have about 10k (approx 180x50x2) CSV files which I want to join together as following, but the inner for loop fails because of some `syntax error`; I cannot see the error in `lastFile`

```
#!/bin/bash
dir='/home/masi/CSV/'
targetDir='/tmp/'
ids=(118 119 120)
channels=(1 2)
for id in ids;

        do
        for channel in channels;

                # example filename P209C1T720-T730.csv
                lastFile="$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'"
                # show warning if last file does not exist
                if [[ -f $lastFile ]]; then
                    echo "Last file "$lastFile" is missing" 
                    exit 1
                fi

                filenameTarget="$targetDir'P'$id'C'$channel'.csv'"
                cat $dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T'*'.csv' > $filenameTarget

        done;
done
```

Error

```
makeCSV.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `lastFile="$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'"'
makeCSV.sh: line 12: `      lastFile="$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'"'
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports

Comment: there is a missing `do` in your second `for` loop

Comment: I really really don't see a `do` in the second `for` loop. Are you really sure that there is a `do`?

Comment: The `do` in the previous line is the `do` for the first `for` loop. The second `for` loop needs another `do`. Syntax of `for` loop: `for name in list; do commands; done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing `do` in your second for loop:

```
for id in ids;

        do
        for channel in channels; do # <----- here ----

                # example filename P209C1T720-T730.csv
                lastFile="$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'"
                # show warning if last file does not exist
                if [[ -f $lastFile ]]; then
                    echo "Last file "$lastFile" is missing" 
                    exit 1
                fi

                filenameTarget="$targetDir'P'$id'C'$channel'.csv'"
                cat $dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T'*'.csv' > $filenameTarget

        done;
done
```

Based on the discussion in the comments I see your confusion with the syntax of the `for` loop.

This is the rough syntax of the `for` loop:

```
for name in list; do commands; done
```

There always must be a `do` before commands and a `;` (or newline) followed by `done` after the commands.

Here is a variation with more newlines:

```
for name in list
do
    commands
done
```

Comment: There is still one problem in the `lastFile` variable. No variables are expanded as expected and `*` is not used as used as expected. Do you understand why?

Comment: if bash does not expand `*` that usually means there are no filenames which match the pattern. If you still have problems with that part then please ask a new question.

Comment: I expanded the other part here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319689/16920

Answer (score 1):

It's properly working:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir='/home/masi/CSV/'
targetDir='/tmp/'
ids=(118 119 120)
channels=(1 2)
for id in ids ; do

        # Add do after ';'
        for channel in channels ; do

                # example filename P209C1T720-T730.csv
                lastFile="$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'"
                # show warning if last file does not exist
                if [[ -f $lastFile ]] ; then
                    echo "Last file "$lastFile" is missing" 
                    exit 1
                fi

                filenameTarget="$targetDir'P'$id'C'$channel'.csv'"
                cat $dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T'*'.csv' > $filenameTarget

        done
done
```

For the future use bash debugger: **bash -x /path/to/your/script**.

Comment: How can you use the asterisk correctly? I get `cat: /home/masi/CSV/PidsCchannelsT*.csv: No such file or directory` where variable expansions are not working and also `*` does not seem to work as expected. Also, all variable expansions are not working.