# Why this expression does not expand in Bash for-for structure?

Tags: bash, for

This works

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/"
targetDir="/tmp/"
id=118
channel=1
filenameTarget=$targetDir"P"$id"C"$channel".csv"
cat $dir"P"$id"C"$channel"T"*".csv" > $filenameTarget
```

Successful output when debugging with `bash -x ...`

```
+ dir=/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/
+ targetDir=/tmp/
+ id=118
+ channel=1
+ filenameTarget=/tmp/P118C1.csv
+ cat /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/P118C1T1000-1010.csv /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/P118C1T1010-1020.csv
```

### The same expression in the for-for loops does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/"
targetDir="/tmp/"
ids=(118 119)
channels=(1 2)
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319682/16920
for id in ids;
        do
        for channel in channels;
                do
                # example filename P209C1T720-T730.csv
                lastFile=$dir'P'$id'C'$channel'T1790-T1800.csv'
                # show error if no last file exists
                if [[ -f $lastFile ]]; then
                    echo "Last file "$lastFile" is missing" 
                    exit 1
                fi

                filenameTarget=$targetDir"P"$id"C"$channel".csv"
                cat $dir"P"$id"C"$channel"T"*".csv" > $filenameTarget

        done;
done
```

Output with the debugger `bash -x ...`

```
+ dir=/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/
+ targetDir=/tmp/
+ ids=(118 119)
+ channels=(1 2)
+ for id in ids
+ for channel in channels
+ lastFile=/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/PidsCchannelsT1790-T1800.csv
+ [[ -f /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/PidsCchannelsT1790-T1800.csv ]]
+ filenameTarget=/tmp/PidsCchannels.csv
+ cat '/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/PidsCchannelsT*.csv'
cat: /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/PidsCchannelsT*.csv: No such file or directory
```

### Code 2

The if clause is always positive also for non-existing files, which is wrong

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/"
startTimes=( $(seq 300 10 1800) )

id=119
channel=1
# example filename P209C1T720-730.csv
firstFile="${dir}P${id}C${channel}T300-T310.csv"
# show error if no first file exists
if [[ ! -f "${firstFile}" ]]; then
    echo "First file "${firstFile}" is missing" 
    exit 1
fi

cat ${firstFile}
```

Output

```
cat: /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/P119C1T300-310.csv: No such file or directory
+ for channel in '"${channels[@]}"'
+ for startTime in '"${startTimes[@]}"'
+ endTime=310
+ filenameTarget=/tmp/P119C2.csv
+ cat /home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/P119C2T300-310.csv
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6

Comment: The error is self explanatory: `/home/masi/Documents/CSV/Case/PidsCchannelsT*.csv: No such file or directory` namely the `Pids` part... Because when you do `for id in ids` `$id` is replaced with the string `ids` instead of using the values saved into the array with the same name...

Comment: You want `for id in "${id[@]}"` (and similarly for the other loop).

Comment: Not at all. That's not an array.

Comment: Maybe you should read through http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/classic_for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ -f $lastFile ]]` is *truthy* if the file exists. It then follows that since you reached `cat $dir"P"$id"C"$channel"T"*".csv"` **that path really does *not* exist.** You probably wanted `if ! [[ -f $lastFile ]]`.

Also, [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) properly - you should be quoting the *variables*. Quoting static strings is a nice safeguard but isn't really necessary. The generally recommended to write the "last" line would be `cat "${dir}P${id}C${channel}T"*'.csv' > "$filenameTarget"`.

Comment: Can you update the question to show the latest code? Otherwise it's hard to know what the issue is…

Comment: There's a `T` missing in your `ls` command…